# Four Cells: An Introduction

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This is a Four Cells puzzle, an area-dividing puzzle.

---

Rules of Four Cells:

> - The grid is to be divided along the grid lines into areas containing exactly four cells.
> - A number in a cell indicates how many of its four sides are segments of area boundaries. Note that this also includes the border of the grid.
> - Line segments of area boundaries should not be left dangling. (See below for an example)
> - An area may contain any multiple number cells (including none).

---

An example grid is shown below for greater clarity.

Example puzzle:

[image: Foseruzu_ex]

Solution to example puzzle:

[image: Foseruzu_ex_ans]

The example below showcases dangling ends and is an incorrect solution to the puzzle.

[image: Foseruzu_ex_wrong]

---

Shown below is the actual puzzle to solve:

[image: Foseruzu_1]

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: (For what it's worth, I usually see it translated just as Four Cells, not the romanized Japanese version. Still looks like a neat puzzle though!)

Comment: This is also known as Palisade in Simon Tatham's collection.

Comment: Corrected Game ID ```6x6n4:2b1i23a1m2b3```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some basic deductions:

> [image]

Next, look at

> the 3 in the center. It must be a "dead end" of a region; if it goes up, then it must go left then, and we have a problem -- we can't make the fourth cell without running into the top 2's region!
>  So the 3 doesn't go up, and R2C3 is a dead end. Making sure to keep regions of size 4, we get to here:
>  [image]

Now let's look at possibilities for another clue:

> specifically, the 1 on the right. It has to be the middle cell of a T tetromino; if the tetromino is oriented as ⊥, ⊤, or ⊢, it will cut off the upper right corner. So it must be a ⊣.
>  [image]

And finally,

> if the 3 region goes down and connects to the two cells below it, the cell in R6C3 will be blocked off. So it must make an S tetromino instead, and this completes the puzzle!
>  [image]

Comment: nooooo i just finished my write-up :'( heheheh