# Hetero-F(our|ive)-Cells

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, polyomino

This is a hybrid of [Four Cells](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/104854/71652) and Five Cells (uses pentominoes instead of tetrominoes), with a global no-repeated-piece rule.

**Rules:**

- The grid is to be divided along the grid lines into areas containing exactly **four or five cells**.
- A number in a cell indicates how many of its four sides are segments of area boundaries. Note that this also includes the border of the grid.
- Line segments of area boundaries should not be left dangling.
- An area may contain multiple number cells (including none).
- No shape may appear twice on the entire grid. Reflections and rotations of a shape are considered as the same shape.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some initial deductions:

> [image]
>  These are pretty straightforward - first make the X with the 0, then extend dead ends until they have at least 4 cells (or as many as you can make).

In the bottom right,

> the 3 joined cells can't use the lower 3, or they trap another cell near the corner. This extends with some "don't repeat the F pentomino" logic to give some more progress:
>  [image]

Now, note

> the 2 clue can't be a dead end of a region. So it must extend up and right, and then it can't be part of the 3 clue. So that places the U in the top right.
>  [image]

And now, there's not much progress that can be made without thinking more globally.

> There are 64 cells in the puzzle. There are only 5 tetrominoes available to us, and we need to use enough tetrominoes so that the remainder is a multiple of 5.
>  The only way to do this is to use **exactly one tetromino**. This also means we'll need to use **all 12 pentominoes**.
>  This lets us resolve the lower right section:
>  [image]

Continuing with this newfound knowledge,

> the 3 clue in R5C1 can't go right, because it couldn't make any unused pentominoes. (And it can't be a tetromino in that case, because the bottom left would be an L tetromino.) So that places the L pentomino.
>
>  Meanwhile, the I pentomino can only go in the top row.
>  [image]
>  We now only have the N, Y, W, and T pentominoes left.

Finishing it off:

> There's only one place the T pentomino can go: in the upper left corner.
>  [image]
>  If the 3 connected with the shape below it and made a Y, we wouldn't have anywhere to put the W pentomino.
>  [image]
>  And finally, there's only one place the Y can go now, and that finishes off the puzzle.

The final answer:

> [image]